# Can we have a similar thing like dos2unix in javascript

Tags: javascript, newline, dos2unix, lf

I want to know whether we can convert from DOS(CR LF) format to UNIX(LF) format in Javascript/JQuery?

In linux/unix, we have a `dos2unix` command and I'm looking similar thing in javascript.

Thanks in advance, happy coding :)

Comment: [`"string".replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)?

Comment: thanks for reply, Can you elaborate your answer ?

Comment: Just a regex substitution like `s/\015\012/\012/g` should do.

Comment: If you don't want to roll your own perhaps search the vast multitude of npm libraries. First I found was [eol](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eol).

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dos2unix

Comment: I want in plain javascript as my requirement is to download a text file from windows to unix format. It is a client side only application so used plain html5 and javascript/jquery.

Comment: Thanks All for the quick reply. I found my answer :)

Below is the solution with string.replace.

`the_string.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n")`

Answer (score 1):

I found answer for my question. Below is the way we can do it in javscript with the help of ["string".replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

`the_string.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n")`

Thanks everyone, happy coding :)